# Where can I find a reference which controls are in which version of MFC?

Tags: mfc

Preferably with visual illustrations... MSDN just lists class-names and what I really want to see is which versions of MFC have nice modern functionality like dockable toobars, collapsible windows, and other graphical niceties.

Does such a 'visual catalog' exist? From MSDN it's not always clear even what each class does without a pretty picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a 'gallery' of MFC controls on MSDN.

The closest thing I can think of are the MFC samples included in Visual Studio. There should be a project like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982842%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) that shows all of the controls with examples of how to use them. The other [samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983962.aspx) in the [MFC Feature Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982354%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) also have workable demos for docking windows, ribbons, etc.